# Volley in Android not attempting to connect

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I've been attempting to get Volley to request data from the internet. Code is below. Forgive the verbose code, this was as quick and dirty test just to see if Volley worked. I'll clean it up once I get it working.

```
public static Option parseJSON(Context context, String stockTicker, String strikePrice, String expiration) {
        final String apikey = "XXXX"; **//key removed just for StackOverflow, but it works**
        String ticker = "&symbol=";
        final String baseURL = "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/quotes?";
        Option option = new Option();

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateforRequest = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyy");
            String formattedDate = simpleDateforRequest.format(simpleDate.parse(expiration));
            String fullTicker = stockTicker + "_" + formattedDate + "C" + strikePrice;
            ticker = ticker + fullTicker;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final String url = baseURL + apikey + ticker;

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                String jsonObject = response.toString();
                Log.d("JSONRequestResponse", "Response: " + jsonObject);
            }
        }, error -> Log.d("JSONRequestResponse", "Error: " + error.toString()));

        queue.add(request);

        Log.d("JSON", "Request" + request + " URL: " + url);
        return option; **//method doesn't create an option yet, but the problem comes well before this.**
    }
```

The problem is that none of the logd within JsonArrayRequest are triggered and the one at the end is just an empty array ("[]"), making me think that Volley isn't attempting to connect.

- I've tried using JsonObjectRequest and StringRequest as well
- I've already added '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET'/> to the manifest, as well as trying "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
- The final URL works. I clicked it for the final logd and it takes me to a JSON page with the right info
- The gradle version is 1.2.1, so it should be the most up-to-date

Again, I'm just testing to see if Volley retrieves a JSON, I haven't gotten to the return Object yet. At this point, I have no idea what it can be. Any help is much appreciated

***UPDATE****************************************

As expected, it doesn't seem like the app is connecting to the internet. I've used this following method to see if there is a connect and it returns false:

```
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    Log.d("CheckPoint", "isNetworkAvailable first line");
    final boolean[] availability = {false};
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                availability[0] = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com").isReachable(5000);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.d("CheckPoint", "isNetworkAvailable UnknownHost!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("CheckPoint", "isNetworkAvailable IOException!");
            }
        }
    }).start();

    Log.d("CheckPoint", "Availability: " + availability[0]);
    return availability[0];
}
```

Comment: Your new code for tjhe is available wouldn't work.  You're changing the value of availability in a thread.  You can't access it immediately on the main thread, it isn't set yet.  If you just want to look for the log as a test, move the log statement into the thread.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan, I actually ran the whole method in a new thread and moved the logd into the try block just to make sure everything synced. Unfortunately the isNetworkAvailable method still ended up return false. I do appreciate the input!

Answer (score 0):

You never called

```
requestQueue.start()
```

Although I have to say-  unless your really need some feature that only Volley gives you, Retrofit is a much easier to use library, and it avoids some problems with Volley (Volley can cause memory issues with large responses or multiple outstanding requests because it needs to hold the entire response as an in memory String, rather than streaming it to a temp file).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I called start before and separately after the .add, but nothing changed. Still blank. I may switch to Retrofit to see if that's easier